# Recently Google Search Console reported some amp errors when I have not AMP applied in my website at all!

Tags: google-search-console, search, amp

Recently Google Search Console reported amp errors. There's no amp applied in my website at all. How is that possible?
Check the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Are those pages really 404 Not Found?   Are the supposed to be so?    If so, it doesn't sound worrying to me.

Comment: Could a previous version of the site have had amp? As it's amp specific errors, and you are not trying to enable amp, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

never mind. It could happen, other pages have any markup, which is same or similar to AMP markup, like CSS class or javascript function names. So Google thought, there *could be* some AMP pages and tried to crawl them. Well, they aren't here, so 404. It is pretty sure, Google will no longer try to crawl AMP pages. Even if Google will try to crawl them, they will remain just in a very small amount.